# Rsync to QNAP NAS fails : No Space on Remote Server (Code 41)

Tags: backup, nas, rsync

Yesterday I replaced old hard drives in a QNAP NAS, which is our backup NAS at the office.  This morning I started syncing data from our Synology NAS, to the QNAP NAS, as I always do:

`rsync -arv [folder] [user]@10.10.0.64:/share/[folder]`

The first folder I copied did so without issue.  Every folder after, however, has failed.

```
user@NAS1:/volume1$ rsync -arv --ignore-errors nearline user@10.10.0.64:/share/
user@10.20.30.64's password: 
sending incremental file list
nearline/#recycle/00000000/748FB706/00000000/
nearline/#recycle/00000000/748FB706/00000000/0000002300000000.TIF
nearline/#recycle/00000000/748FB706/00000000/0000002400000000.TIF
nearline/#recycle/00000000/748FB706/00000000/0000002500000000.TIF
rsync: writefd_unbuffered failed to write 4 bytes to socket [sender]: 
Broken pipe (32)
rsync: write failed on 
/share/nearline/#recycle/00000000/748FB706/00000000/23000.TIF: No space left on device (28)`
rsync error: no space on remote server (code 41) at io.c(1273) [sender=3.0.9]
```

Noticing that `no space left` error, I look at the QNAP's available space in the GUI and with `df -h`.  The QNAP has 3.5TB of 3.6TB free, so that can't be the problem.

---

**Things I've tried**

- Tried to use `--ignore-errors`, which didn't work.
- Tried to exclude the `#recycle` directory, which got a bit further, but still failed.

---

**Hardware Info**

Current NAS : Synology DS1515+

Backup NAS : QNAP TS451

Answer (score 0):

While waiting, I kept modifying the command, and found a solution.  I `cd`'d into the directory I want to sync, and ran this command:

`rsync -arv * user@10.10.0.1:/share/nearline`

It has been syncing the files without issue for five minutes now, but will continue to monitor it should it fail.